# OOP/Function Help

Tags: php, oop, function

I would like some recommendations on the following situation:

I have to build a page that shows all data from 2 tables on a page called "view" with box down below that says "edit".  On the edit page they have the option to edit one row and all of the 2nd table.

How would you write the functions for this.  Would you have each individual row as a function?  or would you combine it into one big function?  - if so how?

Thanks

Jess

Comment: The general practice is to handle one row at a time.

Comment: If I understand your question, you are talking about the way things are being presented to the user. And not much about "oop function" as tag says. In this case, I would have something different, like click and a textbox appears in place, hit <enter> to update (AJAX)

Comment: This question would be better off on programmers exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to answer this question, since functionality of your website and relations between object are not clear.

Generally, if you are doing two non-related actions with significantly different abstractions, I'd recommend to separate these actions into two different methods or even classes. Each functionality unit must have specific responsibilities.